# Fade transition plugin for jQuery : Multiple instances

Tags: jquery

I've been trying to put 2 instances of this script on my site for the whole day and I can't get it to work. It's either one or the other that works, but not both at the same time.

Can you tell me how to put 2 faders in the same page?

http://www.robpoyntz.com/blog/?p=223

Thanks a bunch.

I'm trying to do this :

```
$("#mediaslideshow").fadeTransition({
    ignore: null,
    delayStart: 0,
    pauseTime: 3500,
    transitionTime: 1500,
    manualNavigation: false,
    pauseOnMouseOver: true,
    createNavButtons: false
});

$("#bannertroisquart").fadeTransition({
    ignore: null,
    delayStart: 0,
    pauseTime: 3500,
    transitionTime: 1500,
    manualNavigation: false,
    pauseOnMouseOver: true,
    createNavButtons: false
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This jQuery 'pro' recommends that you **use a more solid plugin such as [jQuery cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/)**.  It's in use by a much wider audience and has tons of options.

**Basic jQuery cycle demos:**

- [Number pagination](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/int2.html#nav)
- [Auto-advance pagination](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/pager.html)
- [Extensive cycle demos list](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/more.html?v2.23)

**Awesome demos:**

- My own work: [The coolest feature-content box you've ever seen](http://jsfiddle.net/morrison/qytuT/) (okay, maybe not)
- [Pittsburgh Sports](http://www.cagintranet.com/code/cycle_demo/)
- [Epic Harley slideshow](http://line25.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/slideshow/demo/demo.html)

Comment: Thanks, you're totally right. I saw this plugin but was not impressed but the demos... I guess I should have looked a bit more :)

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this problem before - it's most likely because the way the script is programmed, it only allows one instance of the fader, and the second time you call it, you're overwriting the properties of the first (and only) instance. I'd recommend you go look on http://plugins.jquery.com/ and find another fade plugin - usually they'll say when they support multiple faders.